# Add new array dynamic with AJAX php

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, wordpress

i'm very confused to add dynamicly array with AJAX php.

The case:

```
function Ajax_Action() {
    $item_id = 10; //dynamicly with item id
    $user_id = 5; //dynamicly with current user id
    $user_data = 'my_cart'; //staticly

    $data_array = array(
        'item_' . $item_id => array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'user_data' => $user_data,
            'item_id' => $item_id,
        ),
    );

    update_post_meta($item_id, 'data_cart', $data_array );
}
```

If i added to cart, value 'data_cart' replaced, i don't want it.
I want every different user add product to cart always update 'data_cart' value with old and new array like this:

```
Array(
   [item_1] = Array(...)
   [item_2] = Array(...)
)
```

Can you understand my question and give the best answer? Thank you :)

Comment: You have some variable scope problem here, where are your $the_id_item, $dynamicly_added_with_current_user & dynamicly_added_with_user_add_item_to_cart variables defined. Btw, you lack $ sign before your last variable

Comment: Well if you want to update existing data instead of overwriting it, that would first of all require that you have the existing data already, resp. that you read it before you add to it. I don’t see that happening in your code - you are just creating a new array.

Comment: @DenisSolakovic , thanks for suggestion, i edit it.